# Is it possible/sensible to use webhooks to get public page post engagement updates?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

A platform I'm working on will need to periodically update engagement data (reaction count, comment count, share count) for a number of public page posts across facebook matching specific criteria. Access to those posts would be gained either via Page Public Content Access or, I reckon, can be also had via webhooks (I gather the Page Public Content Access permission -or, "feature" is still required, though).

Now, with Graph API requests, a public post would be queried in increasing time intervals during a period of time (say, a week) after which you can assume the post will be buried deep down enough that new interactions are numerically irrelevant - so there would be a certain number of Graph API request to that post's specific endpoint.

The possibility to have updates with webhooks (to which I'm new) for this looks interesting, but I have a few questions that seem not to be addressed in detail in the Facebook webhooks docs:

- are Public Page Posts actually "visible" from webhooks? (ie: one can create a webhook subscription to a specific post in the graph?)
- if the above use case is actually feasible, would facebook post to my endpoint for each and every single modification (e.g. "post like" or "new comment") to a post object or would/could these updates be somewhat aggregated (maybe: every X updates or every 10 minutes, whichever is the shortest)?
- would webhooks notifications for a specific post last forever OR is there some kind of expiration (perhaps, that might be configured on subscription) built in?

Comment: No, you need admin access to a page to be able to subscribe it for webhook updates.

Comment: Ah well, API requests it is, then.